# Mysql 4 to 5 - Change script expression

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I'm getting this error under error_log Apache

[Fri Nov 29 15:03:49 2013] [error] [client 81.15.135.11] SELECT COUNT(*),COUNT(DISTINCT UserName),COUNT(DISTINCT CallingStationId) FROM radacct WHERE AcctStartTime LIKE '%2013-11-22%', referer: http://www.company.com/caoad/charts.cgi

[Fri Nov 29 15:02:46 2013] [error] [client 81.15.135.11] SELECT SUM(AcctOutputOctets),SUM(AcctInputOctets) FROM radacct WHERE AcctStartTime LIKE '%2013-11-19%', referer: http://www.company.com/caoad/charts.cgi

```
SELECT COUNT(*),COUNT(DISTINCT UserName),COUNT(DISTINCT CallingStationId)
FROM radacct
WHERE AcctStartTime LIKE '%2013-11-10%'

SELECT SUM(AcctOutputOctets),SUM(AcctInputOctets)
FROM radacct
WHERE AcctStartTime LIKE '%2013-11-09%'
```

The syntax probably changed from Mysql 4 to 5 and I don't know exactly how should I change it to.

If anyone can give me some pointers that would be great. Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Chart::Lines;
do "ho.pl";
$numdays = $forminput{'numdays'};
$partner = $forminput{'partner'};
my $nas = $forminput{'nasidentifier'};
if (!$numdays){
    $numdays = 7;
}
$multiplier = 38;
if ($numdays > 30){
$small=1;
$multiplier = 8;
}
$g = Chart::Lines->new(50+($numdays*$multiplier),500);
@day_names = qw(Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat);
$accum=0;
for (my $count=$numdays; $count>0; $count--) {

($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time() - 60*60*24*$count);
$mon++;
$montext = sprintf "%02d",$mon;
$mdaytext = sprintf "%02d", $mday;
$year = $year + 1900;
if ($partner){
%hotspotpartners = get_hotspot_trading_partners();
my $matchstring;
my $countage=0;
foreach (keys %hotspotpartners){
    if ($hotspotpartners{$_} == $partner){
    if ($countage != 0){
        $matchstring .= " OR ";
    }
    $matchstring .= "NASIdentifier='$_'";
    $countage++;
    }
}

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*),COUNT(DISTINCT UserName),COUNT(DISTINCT CallingStationId) 
FROM radacct 
WHERE AcctStartTime LIKE '%"."$year-$montext-$mdaytext%' AND ($matchstring)";
} else { $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*),COUNT(DISTINCT UserName),COUNT(DISTINCT CallingStationId) FROM radacct WHERE AcctStartTime LIKE '%"."$year-$montext-$mdaytext%'";
}
if ($nas){
        $sql .= " AND NASIdentifier = '$nas'";
}
print STDERR $sql;
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth->execute();
($temp,$unique,$mac) = $sth->fetchrow();
if ($small){
$title="";
} else {
$title = "$day_names[$wday] $mday/$mon";
}
$g->add_pt($title, $temp,$unique,$mac);
$accum = $accum + $temp;
}
$accum = int($accum / $numdays);
my @legend_labels = qw(Total Unique MACS);
$g->set('sub_title' => 'Average : '.$accum.' logins per day');
$g->set('min_val' => 0);
if (!$small){
$g->set('grid_lines' =>'true');
}
$g->set('x_label' =>'Date');
$g->set('y_label' =>'Number of logins');
$g->set('legend_labels' => \@legend_labels);
$g->set('transparent' =>'true');
$g->cgi_png();
```

#

Error log after make changes on the script to:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

#

```
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Scalar value @abbr[$county] better written as $abbr[$county] at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 47., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$last" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 10., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "%forminput" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 10., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$last" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 11., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$last" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 12., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$last" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 15., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$last" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 22., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$last" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 28., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$last" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 35., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 39., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$sql" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 43., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$sql" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 44., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$dbh" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 45., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$sql" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 45., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 47., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "@legend_labels" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 52., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 53., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 54., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 55., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 56., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 57., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 58., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 60., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 61., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "@legend_labels" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 61., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 62., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 63., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "@data" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi line 63., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Execution of /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-day.cgi aborted due to compilation errors., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:33 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Premature end of script headers: chart-day.cgi, referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:34 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$numdays" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-bandwidthhistory.cgi line 6., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:34 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "%forminput" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-bandwidthhistory.cgi line 6., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:34 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$partner" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-bandwidthhistory.cgi line 7., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:34 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "%forminput" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-bandwidthhistory.cgi line 7., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:34 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "%forminput" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-bandwidthhistory.cgi line 8., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:34 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$numdays" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-bandwidthhistory.cgi line 9., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:34 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$numdays" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-bandwidthhistory.cgi line 10., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:34 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$multiplier" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-bandwidthhistory.cgi line 12., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:34 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$numdays" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-bandwidthhistory.cgi line 13., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:34 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$small" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-bandwidthhistory.cgi line 14., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:34 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$multiplier" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-bandwidthhistory.cgi line 15., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
[Fri Nov 29 15:36:34 2013] [error] [client 82.15.145.17] Global symbol "$g" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/ovad/chart-bandwidthhistory.cgi line 17., referer: /ovad/charts.cgi
```

Comment: exacttly WHAT error are you getting? There's nothing wrong with either SQL statement. And why have you tagged this with PHP but are using Perl?

Comment: Please, provide radacct table structure with sample data via sqlfiddle. Try your query there as well.

Comment: Your first lines after the shebang, in any of your perl scripts should be `use strict; use warnings`. Maybe your Problem will be clarified with that.

Comment: @MarcB , Hi Mark just update the post with the error_log

Comment: Are those being produce by something like `error_log($sql)`? Because just showing us the queries tells us nothing. there's nothing wrong with the queries themselves. you need to give us the exact mysql error, e.g. `error_log(mysql_error())`.

Comment: @MarB , the error is showing in error_log from Apache, but the page does what its supposed to, just don't know if the math it try to do is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of field is 'AcctStartTime'? If it's a datetime field (or similar), I don't think you can use 'like' on it.

You probably want:

```
where date(acctStartTime) = '2013-11-09'
```

Comment: its a table used to keep records on a radius controller for hotspot. Account Start Time is when the user first login.

Comment: Yes, but what sort of field is it in the mysql table? Unless it's a varchar or other string-type value, you don't want to use like.

Comment: It's actually more efficient in MySQL to use `where acctStartTime >= "2013-11-09 00:00:00" and acctStartTime <= "2013-11-09 23:59:59"`. Using the `date()` function will cause indexes to not be used.

Comment: Hi Tom Melly, I tried to share a image of the structure but I don't have yet rights to do it here.

Comment: well can you try replacing the 'like' with either my code or jordanm's

Comment: BTW I'm not sure I'd be adding strict and warnings to the perl code until you've solved your original problem.